# How to debug migration from Windows Phone 8 to UWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uwp

I'm working on UWP version of the application which currently in the Store but for Windows Phone 8. The WP8 version have some local data which I need to convert to new format when UWP version starting. How can I debug that process ?
I've tried to associate UWP version with same store app name and then deployed  package on the device where WP8 version was. But new version has not replaced old one.
I see one way: create fake app in the store, upload old package, install on device, then upload new package and update. But it too painfull...

Comment: Local data should persist, so you can just debug your code. Put old data in `%localappdata%\Packages\<YOUR APP>\LocalState` folder and debug migration.

Comment: @DavidKosorin I'm not sure. I've found the way to update which is described bellow. But UWP version don't see files in local storage which were saved by WP8 version. Do you know something about compatibility between WP8 Silverlight and UWP local storages ?

Comment: Check 2nd paragraph on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx
But I'm not sure If this is for old SL app. You have to try it with some dummy data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy ProdictId from old WMAppManifest.xml to PhoneProductId in new Package.appxmanifest. After that new UWP package replaces old WP8 one.
And yes, files in local storage were created with old WP8 Silverlight app will be accessible from UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the package identity in de Package.appxmanifest to the one of your WP8 app. When a user upgrades Windows 10 Mobile they will get the UWP version update of your app when they have the WP8 version installed.

Comment: I've already used same identity when associated app with store.

Comment: I've probably found the answer. You need to copy ProdictId from old WMAppManifest.xml to PhoneProductId in new Package.appxmanifest. After that new UWP package replaces old WP8 one